# How to write mock unit test case for ExecuteNonQuery & ExecuteScalar & GetDataSet method

Tags: c#, testing, case, moq

I am writing a unit test case for my application.In my application, I am using SQLite datebase.I want to mock following methods.Like,ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteScalar, GetDataSet.I am writing my methods below.

Please, any one help me to write mock unit test case for following method.

**ExecuteNonQuery**

```
using (SQLiteConnection objCon = objISQLite.OpenConnection(DBNAME))
{
     objCon.Open();
     using (SQLiteCommand objCmd = new SQLiteCommand(strSQL, objCon))
     {
           intRetValue = objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           objCmd.Dispose();
     }
     objCon.Close();
     objCon.Dispose();
}
```

**ExecuteScalar**

```
using (SQLiteConnection objCon = OpenConnection(DBNAME))
{
      objCon.Open();
      using (SQLiteCommand objCmd = new SQLiteCommand(strSQL, objCon))
      {
            objRetValue = objCmd.ExecuteScalar();
            objCmd.Dispose();
      }
      objCon.Close();
      objCon.Dispose();
}
```

**GetDataSet**

```
using (DataSet dsData = new DataSet())
{
      using (SQLiteConnection objCon = OpenConnection(DBNAME))
      {
           objCon.Open();
           using (SQLiteDataAdapter objAdp = new SQLiteDataAdapter(strSQL,objCon))
                 {
                       dsData.Reset();
                       objAdp.Fill(dsData);
                       objAdp.Dispose();
                 }
                 objCon.Close();
                 objCon.Dispose();
      }
      return (#Dataset);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to apply the dependency inversion principle that states that you should depends upon abstractions, not upon concretions.

This is the 'D' of the S.O.L.I.D. acronym (see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) for SOLID programming and [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) for the dependency inversion principle)

Here you are tightly coupled with a concrete usage of SQLite for your database accesses.
In the class you are using, you should depend over an abstraction of database access (let's name it DatabaseManager) that you will mock.

Also, you will prefer using interfaces (i.e. IDbCommand over SQLiteCommand, ...) as this is more easily maintainable, more explicit on your intentions and more easily mockable.

For instance you code could become something like:

```
interface IDatabaseManager
{
  IDbConnection OpenConnection(string databaseName);
  IDbCommand CreateCommand(string command, IDbConnection connection);
}


class MyClass
{
    private IDatabaseManager  _databaseManager;
    public MyClass(IDatabaseManager databaseManager)
    {
        _databaseManager = databaseManager;
    }

    public void ExecutScalarMethod()
    {
        using (var objCon = _databaseManager.OpenConnection(DBNAME))
        {
          objCon.Open();
          using (SQLiteCommand objCmd = _databaseManager.CreateCommand(strSQL, objCon))
          {
                objRetValue = objCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                objCmd.Dispose();
          }
          objCon.Close();
          objCon.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

By injecting an abstraction of DbManager in your class you are reducing coupling between your class and the concrete usage of the database (here SQLite) and therefor improving its unit-testability.

Unit testing this class becomes easy as you just have to pass a mock of IDatabaseManager that you will setup to return mocks of IDbConnection and IDbCommand to verify your assertions.